# Are Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu's compatible with html preview in github?

Tags: html, github, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to host a simple html page using github (html preview) and the bootstrap dropdown menu inside the navbar won't respond (i.e. toggle). Everything else works fine using github except the dropdown menu.

****Just to be clear, the bootstrap dropdown menu code works perfectly when using my local host and when executed inside of codepen. There seems to be some unknown issue with github and bootstrap 4 dropdown menu. The dropdown menu is somehow disabled when previewing the html page in a github repository****

I've included a simple example to help illustrate the non-functioning dropdown menu problem when viewed in github html preview.
https://github.com/fswylie01/github_sample

Here's a basic example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>dropdown example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

<body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" 
             data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown Menu
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./link.html">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./link.html">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./link.html">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="./abc.html">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

I would like to include this feature with my github code and need some advice.

Thanks, Frank

Comment: place your problematic code here - external links are not OK. please read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MaciejS. I've added a basic code snippet for you to review.